# How to calculate an infinite sum to 100 exact digits with NSum?

Tags: numerics, summation, precision-and-accuracy

In the discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3419778/198592 I stumbled of the question how to calculate the sum

$$s= \sum _{n=3}^{\infty } \frac{n \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)}{4^{n-2}}$$

to high precision.

I used `NSum[]` and played around with `WorkingPrecision` and `Method`, and the best I could get was 29 digits:

```
NSum[(n Cot[\[Pi]/n])/4^(n - 2), {n, 3, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 29, 
 Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]

(* Out[123]= 0.85222988130298006255574122938 *)
```

Increasing `WorkingPrecision` did not help as can be see from

```
sn[w_] := NSum[(n Cot[\[Pi]/n])/4^(n - 2), {n, 3, \[Infinity]}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> w, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]

Table[{w, Length[RealDigits[sn1[w]][[1]]]}, {w, 24, 32}]

(* Out[126]= {{24, 24}, {25, 24}, {26, 26}, {27, 26}, {28, 27}, {29, 29}, {30, 28}, {31, 
  28}, {32, 28}} *)
```

How can I get more exact digits, say 50 or 100?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't had much success with `NSum`, and would suggest to sum terms until you reach the desired accuracy.

If you sum terms from $n=3$ to $m$ (for some large $m$), then you can get an estimate of the error by summing a series-expansion of the remaining terms. For large $n$, your term is approximately `(16*n^2/π - 16*π/3)/(4^n)`.

Example: sum exactly up to $m=1000$,

```
With[{m = 1000},
    N[Sum[4^(2-n)*n*Cot[π/n], {n, 3, m}], 10^3]]
(*    0.85222988130298006255...    *)
```

The error is approximately

```
With[{m = 1000},
  N[Sum[(16*n^2/π - 16*π/3)/(4^n), {n, m+1, ∞}], 10^3]]
(*    1.4825646546726929...*10^-596    *)
```

So with 1000 terms we've gotten almost 600 correct digits. That's roughly $\ln(4)/\ln(10)=0.60...$ digits per term.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elegant solution. Nice measure "digits per term".

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the result with `NSum`, use more terms for the extrapolation to get improved accuracy, increase `WorkingPrecision` to handle rounding error:

```
n1 = NSum[(n Cot[\[Pi]/n])/4^(n - 2), {n, 3, \[Infinity]}, 
  NSumTerms -> 150, WorkingPrecision -> 150, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]
Precision[%]
(*
0.85222988130298006255574122919169970056195391003233107805879735766771\
1344129758954639414777305170965859236369534172722

117.849
*)

n2 = NSum[(n Cot[\[Pi]/n])/4^(n - 2), {n, 3, \[Infinity]}, 
  NSumTerms -> 250, WorkingPrecision -> 200, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]
Precision[%]
(*
0.85222988130298006255574122919169970056195391003233107805879735766771\
1344129758954639414777305170965859236369534172721688746076335155778061\
150336000423518013038870770528545386615821

180.328
*)
```

The higher-precision result agrees with the 117-digit result to all digits (when rounded to the same precision).

```
n1 - n2
(*  0.*10^-118  *)
```

Comment: @ Michael E2 thank you for this very instructive answer to the question as requested in the OP (using NSum). I had thought about this parameter before but I did not try to play with it.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze You're welcome. It's less successful on the oscillatory sum of `(Sin[k]/k)^7`. (You probably need to go out to well over 500000 terms to get a stable result, since `k^-7` equals `0.5*^-40` around `k -> 570000`.)

Answer (score 2):

My question has been fully answered by the solutions of @Roman and @ Michael E2.

Here I'd like to add a comment to this solution.

Sometimes we need really very many terms to reach the required number of exact digits.

Here's an example of an infinite sum which was discussed earlier ([Possible bug in infinite sum Sum[(Sin[k]/k)^m,{k,0,∞}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157444/16361)) and can be calculated in closed form:

```
s=Table[Sum[(Sin[k]/k)^n, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}], {n, 7, 7}]

(* Out[200]= {1 + (-23040 + 129423 \[Pi] - 201684 \[Pi]^2 + 
   144060 \[Pi]^3 - 54880 \[Pi]^4 + 11760 \[Pi]^5 - 1344 \[Pi]^6 + 
   64 \[Pi]^7)/46080} *)
```

With fourty digits the result is

```
N[%, 40]

(* Out[201]= {1.302724350729152883809457286983788824390} *)
```

If we use `Sum` to calculate these 40 digits correctly we need **no less than 340'000 terms**:

```
N[1 + Sum[(Sin[k]/k)^7, {k, 1, 340000}], 40]

(* Out[229]= 1.302724350729152883809457286983788824390 *)
```

Only one term less changes the last digit from $0$ to $1$:

```
N[1 + Sum[(Sin[k]/k)^7, {k, 1, 340000-1}], 40]

(* Out[239]= 1.302724350729152883809457286983788824391 *)
```

Comment: `NSum` does much better if you break `(Sin[k]/k)^7` up into terms of `Exp[m I k]/k^7`, `m = 1, 3, 5, 7`.  You need less than 1000 terms with Wynn-Epsilon.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting hint. I understand it as a statement about the series for $\operatorname{Li}(7,e^{m i})$

Comment: Yes, that's a succinct way of putting it, but I was thinking that the numerical behavior of terms like `Exp[3 I k]/k^7` is easier to extrapolate than the sine form.